# Use of unresolved identifier when declaring variable inside a function declaration in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I am declaring a function for my program that includes a variable, but the variable is not read by the TextField in the function. Here is my code(which is not inside a struct):

```
func FieldText() {        
    var text : String = ""
    TextField("Type here", text : $text)        
}
```

The $text inside the TextField function is giving the error. I have tried declaring the variable like this:

```
var text = String("")
```

This also gave the error. How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you expect this code to do? You cannot just put a `$` on arbitrary variables, but it's not clear what you're expecting to happen to help you write it correctly. What do you expect the `:` here to do? That's not legal syntax, but I'm not certain what you wanted it to mean. In any question where there is an error, you need to indicate what the error was, not just "gave an error."

Comment: The error was the statement in the title, about an unresolved identifier. The $ indicates the variable the textfield edits, something I have successfully done in the past. I want the textfield to edit the variable that is declared in the function. The : is used in variable declaration that is used successfully in other parts of the program, but I also tried the other method as well. The other : is used in the TextField syntax, and has worked in the past. I hope I cleared this up enough.

Comment: "The $ indicates the variable the textfield edits." That is not what `$` means. It means to access the underlying property rather than the property wrapper's projection (typically a Binding). You can't just apply them to arbitrary variables. Just calling `TextField()` doesn't create a text field. You need to return this to something in a View hierarchy. You can't just place it in top level functions. It doesn't *do* anything. It just defines a View (which you then throw away rather than returning). The `:` I'm talking about is the one in `text : $text`. That's not a variable declaration.

Comment: I see. So what I am trying to do is not possible in a function? I can’t use a wrapper on it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean here. You can return Views from functions, but you're not doing that (you're not returning anything). That's very common and recommended. And passing a local variable to the binding doesn't make sense, because nothing else could ever access the result.

Comment: That is precisely why I wanted to do it this way, so that nothing else could ever access the result. By the way, I am new to Swift, but that was probably obvious.

Comment: So you want a text field that lets the user edit it, but the program doesn't care about the result? That's no problem if it's what you're looking for. (I just remembered why you used `:` here; sorry, that's correct syntax. Adding spaces around it threw me off and made me think it was a `?:` operator. You don't typically put a space in front of  `:` in function calls)

Comment: That is correct. I want to add this function to a ForEach command that creates them. It serves no practical purpose, just something I have been trying to figure out.

Comment: Not a problem; one sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the result of a TextField, you can pass it a `.constant`. You also need to return the TextField, however, so that the caller can use it.

```
func FieldText() -> some View  {
    TextField("Type here", text: .constant(""))
}
```